# facing "PDO Connection Error" when try to deploy symfony project to Debian

Tags: php, deployment, symfony1, pdo, mysql-error-2013

My project works fine on my local. When i put it on Debian, I am facing an error:

> PDO Connection Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110

I searched it on the internet, everyone thinks its because of databases.yml file. I tried lots of one but could not fix the prob.

Comment: [What does MySQL Error 2013 mean?](http://serverfault.com/questions/29597/what-does-mysql-error-2013-mean)

Comment: i am afraid i didnt try to write 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. it was because of this trick. thanks for your comment about error 2013'

Answer (score 0):

```
For the PDO, I think all you have to activate it is to add in your php.ini the
```

extension=pdo.so
line.

For curl and imagemagick extensions, are the modules installed?

sudo apt-get install php5-curl php5-imagick